# Adding a Phaser sprite using a javascript ES6 class

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I have the following minimal code, using Phaser.js 3.11.0 and Javascript ES6:

```
class Ship extends Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Image {
    constructor(scene, x, y) {
        super(scene, x, y, 'ship');
    }
}

class Scene extends Phaser.Scene {
    preload() {
        this.load.image('ship', require('../assets/ship.png'));
    }

    create() {
        this.ship1 = this.physics.add.existing(new Ship(this, 50, 70));
        this.ship2 = this.physics.add.image(150, 70, 'ship');
    }
}

new Phaser.Game({
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 200,
    height: 150,
    scene: Scene,
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
            debug: true,
        },
    },
});
```

Using `this.physics.add.existing(new Ship(this, 50, 70))` doesn't work: the sprite is not displayed, even if the debug bounding box is shown, with the right size.

Here is the rendered output:

[image: Rendered output]

If I don't use physics, the sprite displays correctly:

```
class Ship extends Phaser.GameObjects.Image {
    ...
}

class Scene extends Phaser.Scene {
    ...
    create() {
        this.ship1 = this.add.existing(new Ship(this, 50, 70));
        ...
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by changing the `create()` method:

```
create() {
    this.ship1 = this.add.existing(new Ship(this, 50, 70));
    this.physics.world.enable([ this.ship1 ]);
}
```

Indeed, you can read in the [API documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.World.html#enable), about the `Phaser.Physics.Arcade.World#enable()` method:

> Calling factory methods encapsulates the creation of a Game Object and
>   the creation of its body at the same time. *If you are creating custom
>   classes then you can pass them to this method to have their bodies
>   created*.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you call the Arcade physics in the config main.js?ie:

```js
const config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight,
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
            debug: true
        }
    },
    scene: [
        BootScene,
        LevelScene,
    ]
}
```